# Windows 7 reboots after Blue Screen

Tags: windows-7, bsod

**EDIT**

After a second attempt using EasyRE I could get rid of BSoD, but then it wouldn't boot anymore. Even before Windows starts to boot it loaded a screen as the recovery media was inserted (couldn't get over this).

Checked a few minidumps on [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) and it pointed, it seems, to some driver failure.  It was too late anyway. **Was avoiding, but ended reformatting.**

---

Notebook always reboots after a blue screen, right after of showing Windows logo ("Starting Windows").

**None of these work:**

- Safe Mode
- Last Known Good Configuration
- Low-resolution video (VGA Mode) in Windows
- Disable driver signature
- Debugging Mode
- Directory Services Restore Mode

**DID NOT SOLVE**

- `CHKDSK /F/R`
- EasyRE – Tried [Easy Recovery Essentials](https://neosmart.net/EasyRE/Features/), but can't get to really use it. I've made a bootable USB drive, but I'm stuck on this error "grub_divmod64_full".
- `sfc /scannow` – it returns the old fashioned error: "There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete. Restart Windows and run sfc again"
- any repair attempt (using HP Built in recovery tools)

**BLUE SCREEN MESSAGE**

```
STOP: 0x000000F4 (0X0000000000000003, 0XFFFFFA800A439B10 ...)
```

[image: BlueScreen of Death - 0x000000F4]

**SYSTEM**

- HP Pavilion dm4-2175br
- Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit

Comment: 0xF4 means [`CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @DanielB, on that link I can see that the each parameter has a meaning. How can I convert the hex code (0x0..) into something more signifcant? I am imagining that I can find the name of the program and then remove it by prompt maybe...

Comment: `BlueScreenView` will do all that.

Comment: @Ramhound, but I can't start the computer Ram...Can I still use BlueScreenView on a third computer?

Comment: If you transfer the generated dump file to another computer.

Comment: @Ramhound, where is it stored?